# ImageView And Image JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have `ImageView` object defined in FXML called `nameImage`.

I want to load an `Image` if the condition gets satisfied.

```
String name = playerNameFld.getText();
    if ((name == null) || (name.trim().equals(""))) {
        uspesno = false;
        nameImage.setImage(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/images/error.png"), 25.0, 25.0, true, true));
    } else {
        uspesno = true;

    }
```

And I have tried various `InputStream` but it returns **InputStream must not be null**..

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just means you have the path to the image file wrong. If you start the path with a `/`, it will be relative to the classpath. So you need to have the `images` directory at the root of the classpath, and the `error.png` inside there.